# Unable to Generate Same Account from MetaMask Mnemonic in EthereumJSWallet

Tags: ethereumjs, hd-wallets, ethereumjs-tx

I've been unable to generate the Account I see in MetaMask in EthereumJSWallet even if I use the same mnemonic.

Due to the lack of documentation, I may be misunderstanding how to do so.
I have run the following 2 code-blocks in a Truffle Node console in my Terminal but I never got the correct result.

The variable `mnemonic` holds my MetaMask 12 word string. Per the [HD Wallet API](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet#hd-wallet-api) section of the EthereumJSWallet docs, I should "use bip39 to create [a seed] from a BIP39 mnemonic." However, I'm still unable to generate the appropriate account.

Neither `wallet_test` nor any of the derived paths in either of the 2 code-snippets below correspond to my first account.

Attempt 1:

```
var seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic)
var wallet_test = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed)
wallet_test.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0/0")
wallet_test.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0")
```

Attempt 2:

```
var seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedHex(mnemonic)
var wallet_test = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed)
wallet_test.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0/0")
wallet_test.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0")
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will generate the same address from the mnemonic that MetaMask, MyEtherWallet, etc

```
const bip39 = require('bip39');
const hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey');

const mnemonic = 'party box feel talent peace tiger endorse defy cheese girl tumble mail';
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic);

const hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);
const myWallet = hdwallet.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0/0").getWallet();

console.log(`Address: ${myWallet.getAddressString()}`);
console.log(`Private Key: ${myWallet.getPrivateKeyString()}`);
```

It doesn't add the checksum to the address

- `0x999c43b9dd689b9a0bf12ce097663857f62ffbe7` without checksum
- `0x999C43B9DD689b9a0bF12Ce097663857f62ffbe7` with checksum

Comment: how to use same code in flutter,

Comment: @IshwarChandraTiwari Sorry, but I've never used flutter. It is better if you ask a a new question about that.

Comment: To generate a seed you need a mnemonic and a password. In the above code, What is used for the password in the code above? Is it generated internally within the line "bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic)"?

Comment: @VedaSadhak There's an optional second parameter in `bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic, *password*)`. It is assumed to be an empty string if none is provided.