# Mnemonic and HD Path in Ganache and ethereumjs-tx gives different private key and address

Tags: wallets, javascript, ethereumjs, ganache, hd-wallets

I am having difficulty reproducing the private key and address using the mnemonic and HD path provided by Ganache.

**Mnemonic**

> weird farm vast surge upper truth answer end radar impact mind jeans

**HD Path**

> /44'/60'/0'/0/0

[image]

[image]

**JS Code to Reproduce Keys/Addresses**

```
var hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey')

let rootNode = hdkey.fromMasterSeed('weird farm vast surge upper truth answer end radar impact mind jeans')
console.log('Address: ', rootNode.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0/0").getWallet().getAddressString())
console.log('Private Key: ', rootNode.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0/0").getWallet().getPrivateKeyString())
```

**JS Output**

> Address:  0xccb154949e497124538e918fbc3146500ebbe38e
>
> Private Key:  0xa0f34e8dddc55fb9a59a00f58499faa96bebfe1b47b5b821f6f2bb303895c309

**Question:** Why are the address and private key produced by the JS code (`ethereumjs-wallet`) different from the one in Ganache?

*Using Ganache 1.2.2 on Mac OSX, ethereumjs-wallet 0.6.2*

Comment: Doesn't easiest way check source code of ganache-core? https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core

Comment: This might help you https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/60354